# Get user location with "Device Only" in Android

Tags: java, gps, location, android-gps, fusedlocationproviderclient

**Context:**

I have been using `FusedLocationProviderClient` to get user's location.
When the phone is in High Accuracy mode, everything works as expected.
However, not all phones are in high accuracy.
So, how can I manage to get the user location by GPS only

**What I've tried so far:**

1 - Tried this with `FusedLocationProviderClient`:

```
 providerClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                Log.e(TAG,"CALLBACK RECEIVED");
                processNewLocation(locationResult.getLastLocation());
            }
        };

locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
locationRequest.setInterval(LocationConstant.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
locationRequest.setFastestInterval(LocationConstant.FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

providerClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
                    locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
```

When location is in Device Only, location callback is never called, but works perfectly if it is in high accuracy(Also changed `setPriority()` to every priority and no luck).

2-Tried this with Location Manager:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new MyLocationListener());
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new MyLocationListener());
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new MyLocationListener());

 private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            String message = String.format(
                    "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
            );
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Provider status changed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

Still the same result

Comment: Has nobody experienced this before?